# Prepare a method call for execution

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to delay a prepared method call (prepared= all parameters already set) for execution. Example:

I have a textfield with the following listener method:

```
var storedRequest = null;
function doAjaxRequest() {
    //if there is no request at this moment, do the request
    //otherwise: store the request and do nothing

} 
//will be executed after a request is done
function callbackAjaxRequestComplete() {
    //is storedRequest != null --> Execute that request (the last one)
}
```

So, is there a possiblity to store a PREPARED method call for execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var preparedMethod = method.bind(null, param1, param2, param3 /*, ... etc */);`

[`Function.prototype.bind`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
var preparedOperation = function() {
  return actualOperation(param1, param2, param3);
};
```

Then a call at any time to "preparedOperation" will be a call to your actual function.

The [Functional.js](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) library has some interesting support code for that sort of thing.

Comment: An alternative to Functional.js would be [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)